# How does Python handle boolean values with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, python-2.7, return

If I have a function which returns a boolean value based on two or more conditions, does Python check every condition?

More specifically, this is a theoretical function:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x < y and f2(x, y) == 1
```

If `f2` takes a while to execute, should I change `f` to this?

```
def f(x, y):
    if x >= y: return False
    return f2(x, y) == 1
```

Will Python automatically return False if `x` is greater than or equal to `y` because of the `and` up ahead?
Which is the faster of the two and why?

My question would similarly apply also with `or` statements, if the first condition is true does it keep evaluating the next conditions?

Comment: This isn't really about the `if` statement, but about `and` and `or` expressions. (As you apparently already guessed, given your `return` statement.)

Comment: Also, it's worth knowing how you can test this yourself: Write `def f2(x, y): print('f2 ran')`, then call `f(0, 1)` and see if it prints anything. (If it doesn't, you'd still want to check the documentation to make sure that's guaranteed by the language… but if it does, you'd know Python doesn't short-circuit.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions): "The Boolean operators `and` and `or` are so-called short-circuit operators: their arguments are evaluated from left to right, and evaluation stops as soon as the outcome is determined."

Comment: It might be good to add a link to the docs, instead of just quoting them. But otherwise, +1.